# PHP Average Values in Multiple Arrays to 1 Array

Tags: php, arrays, average

I have an array full of numbers and I can easily get the average of one array with.

```
if(count($averageprice)) {
$averageprice= array_filter($averageprice);
$averageprice= array_sum($averageprice)/count($averageprice);
}
```

But say I have 4 arrays all with prices. They are all in the right order and contain the same amount of values. How can I create a single array that keeps the order of each value but averages it between all arrays?

Thanks!

Edit for better example:

```
$array1 =array(10,15,20);
$array2 =array(14,13,22);
$array3 =array(12,18,26);
```

I want a new array that averages all the values in the array into one array. Note the amount of arrays isn't always the same per each time. However no matter how many arrays it is, they will always have the same amount of values in it. (Sometimes 4, sometimes 8, etc)

Comment: Single array with all items in it, or an array that has elements that are the average of each of your existing arrays? A sample of your arrays and your desired output is needed, as well as what you've tried beyond working with the single array.

Comment: Let's see some sample data and your EXACT desired result from the sample data. How is your current snippet failing you? [mcve]

Comment: Single array that has elements with average of existing arrays. I have spent a couple hours with no where to go, was only able to find out how to get average of 1 array. I added some more details on what im trying to figure out.

Comment: If the number of input arrays is variable, then we (volunteers) won't be able to dynamically code up your statically declared arrays `$array1`, `$array2` ... Is it okay for us to have a stable starting point like: `$arrays = [$array1, $array2, ...]`? and we'll just imagine that you can generate a single input variable to suit?  What is your EXACT desired result from the sample data?

Comment: Desired result is an array where all the value1 and value2 etc is averaged from all input arrays. The reply someone gave below is awesome and I can go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST WAY**: arrays in different variables

```
$arr0 = [0,10,2];
$arr1 = [0,20,4];
$arr2 = [0,30,6];
```

Note: array_filter will remove the 0's... For example: the average
of [0, 10, 2] will be 6 (i.e.: (10 + 2) / 2) and NOT (0+10+2)/3 = 4. Is
this really what you mean? Do you want to discard 0's before averaging?

```
$arr0 = array_filter($arr0);
$arr1 = array_filter($arr1);
$arr2 = array_filter($arr2);
```

```
print_r($arr0); // (just to point out again the previous comment)
```

```
Array
(
  [1] => 10
  [2] => 2
)
```

**THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE:**

```
$averages = array_map(function($a){return array_sum($a)/count($a);}, [$arr0, $arr1, $arr2]);
```

```
print_r($averages)
```

```
Array
(
  [0] => 6
  [1] => 12
  [2] => 18
)
```

**SECOND WAY**: All the arrays inside a bigger array.

```
$arrs = [[0,10,2], [0,20,4], [0,30,6]];
$arrs = array_map(function($a){return array_filter($a);}, $arrs);
$result = array_map(function($a){return array_sum($a) / count($a);},  $arrs);
```

```
print_r($arrs);
```

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [1] => 10
          [2] => 2
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [1] => 20
          [2] => 4
      )

  [2] => Array
      (
          [1] => 30
          [2] => 6
      )

)
```

```
print_r($result);
```

```
Array
(
  [0] => 6
  [1] => 12
  [2] => 18
)
```

Comment: I see where people’s confusion came though. I didn’t want to average each array against itself, I meant to average value1 across all arrays and value2 across all arrays. So that the last single arrays value1 was the average of all other arrays value1 and value2 the average value2 of all other arrays. But I think I understand well enough from now. Thanks!

Comment: Oh... Well... I don't understand very well the statement of what you need. If you can manage to state it in a "more explicit" way, perhaps I can try to help... For example: if you make an example, with all the numbers, and you proceed step by step, showing the output that you want in each step... That could help to understand. There is a lot of vocabulary that is not clear to me. "average against itself", "average a value across arrays"; etc. If you can write an example, it would simplify a lot the task of understanding the statement; and I will do my best to try to help.

Comment: It’s for a website of speed runs. Let’s say one game has 4 checkpoints that tally up how many seconds it took to get there since the last checkpoint. So we might have an array of 4 values. Say 403, 246, 548, 648. Now let’s say we have a second persons speed run of the same game. Say 387, 230, 520, 700. And so on. The new array would have the average of these two arrays, so average of 403 and 387 for its first value, 246 and 230 for its second value and so on. This way we can get an average of every persons time at each checkpoint in a new array I hook up to my graph. (Graph works fine)

Comment: You can transpose your matrix of values and compute using the function that I mentioned in my comment... Like this:
`$values = [[403, 246, 548,648], [387, 230, 520, 700]];`
`$values = array_map(null, ...$values);`
`$result = array_map(function($a){return array_sum($a) / count($a);},  $values);`